# How to execute the command after sudo su

Tags: shell, sh, monit, cf-bosh

I need to execute "monit restart haproxy" command  after sudo su.

This is my script.sh

```
sudo su
monit restart haproxy.
```

Here if i will execute the script.sh file then it will hang and it is not executing the monit restart haproxy command.

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376199/sudo-su-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bin-bash-when-does-it-matter-which-is-used) comes some information about sudo su. You need to enter password for sudo or su command, here is some quote from link i posted that may be the source of your problem:

> sudo - sudo is meant to run a single command with root privileges. But unlike su it prompts you for the password of the current user. This user must be in the sudoers file (or a group that is in the sudoers file). **By default, Ubuntu "remembers" your password for 15 minutes, so that you don't have to type your password every time.**

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo su -c - root "monit restart haproxy"
```

verify that your shell has the -c option which sends command via su. Tested the command on RHEL9. This option or something similar should be available in your shell as well.

ensure that you do have sudoer access to run su.

you can also run sudo without password with appropriate sudo definition

```
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

or as appropriate in your environment.

CAUTION: use elevated privileges carefully.